# What is the source of Python3 Memory error? And how to solve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, memory

I wanted to plot .csv files in a loop. By searching around in Stack I found the solution to be- to use plt.figure(). This did solve my problem when I ran it for 2 files. But when I tried this 20 files it gives me MEMORY ERROR. It runs upto 6th file and then throws the error.

The .csv files I am importing each have sizes approximately (800,000~1mil) x 10.

Failed Solutions/debugging/source of problem-

I know that when you import huge files you may be led to memory error(again info from Stack). But here I am loading the files into same variable over and over. Hence I did not expect memory error as I am not using more memory for each loop.

This is not due to individual files as I successfully ran the program in batches - (1,5),(5,10),(10,15),(15-20). But I want this to happen in a single go.

I tried to define functions for plotting hoping to avoid the problem. But again faced the same problem.

I think I can avoid this problem if I can refresh Python database(? I meant something like cache in browsers) after completion of every loop. But how can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

P.S - If I can somehow speed up the program that would be a bonus.

This is the program

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

global n,data1
n = '/media/gautam/New Volume/IIT/Cosmology/2nd year/NEW Codes/k(0.1)_NO-DM.csv'
data1 = np.genfromtxt(n,delimiter=',',dtype=None)

for k in range(0,20):
    a = '/media/gautam/New Volume/IIT/Cosmology/2nd year/NEW Codes/k_(0.1)_%d.csv'%k
    data2 = np.genfromtxt(a,delimiter=',',dtype=None)
    plt.figure()
    diff = data1 - data2
    plt.plot(np.log10(data1[:,1]),np.absolute(diff[:,6]),label='|diff_d|')
    plt.xlabel('log(a)')
    plt.ylabel('|diff_d|')
    plt.legend()
    plt.title('q_d = %d '%data2[0,10])
    plt.savefig('/media/gautam/New Volume/IIT/Cosmology/2nd year/NEW Codes/Fig/k_(0.1)_%d_diff.png'%k)
```

Comment: Two possibilities. One is to do: `del data2` and `gc.collect()` as soon as `data2` is no longer needed. Another is to us `multiprocessing` to do your processing one data file at a time. When a `SubProcess` completes, its memory is freed.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I tried the first option. It prolonged the problem for a bit. But after a few loops more than before I again face the same issue. I think it might the plot data's. How can I delete them when they are not even assigned a variable? I don't know anything about multi processing. But I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this will help. From [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html): `If you are creating many figures, make sure you explicitly call “close” on the figures you are not using, because this will enable pylab to properly clean up the memory.`

Comment: @JohnAnderson Yay, it's working perfectly and pretty quickly too. Add this as an answer. It will help others too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) says:

```
    If you are creating many figures, make sure you explicitly call “close”
on the figures you are not using, because this will enable pylab to properly
clean up the memory.
```

So, if you are having memory issues, add a call to `plt.close()` at the bottom of your `for` loop.